# Sorting documents by sum of specific field in array of other referenced documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

My main schema sort of looks like this:

```
 _id: id,
 random: random, 
 cards: [objectId, objectId, ...]   //ref to cards
```

ex of card:

```
 _id: id,
 random: random, 
 random: random,
 clicks: 15.
```

I would like to sort the top schema by the sum of clicks within the cards.

Comment: @Takis_ ok thy, always learning!

Answer (score 0):

Query1

- lookup to do the left join, and joined card documents to be an array
  (join happens if array contains the card `_id`)
- sum the clicks
- sort by the field that has the sum

*if you want descending use `sort -1` instead of `1`

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70328300-m)

```js
mainColl.aggregate(
[{"$lookup": 
   {"from": "cardCollection",
    "localField": "cards",
    "foreignField": "_id", 
    "as": "clickSum"}},
 {"$set": {"clickSum": {"$sum": "$clickSum.clicks"}}},
 {"$sort": {"clickSum": 1}}])
```

Query2

- same like the above but does the calculation before the join
  (its better but slightly bigger code)

[Test code here](https://cmql.org/play/?q=70328300-1-m)

```js
mainColl.aggregate(
[{"$lookup": 
    {"from": "cardsCollection",  
      "localField": "cards",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "pipeline": 
      [{"$group": {"_id": null, "clicksSum": {"$sum": "$clicks"}}}],
      "as": "clicksSum"}},
  {"$set": {"clicksSum": {"$arrayElemAt": ["$clicksSum.clicksSum", 0]}}},
  {"$sort": {"clickSum": 1}}])
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: if it works good enough and its usefull , upvote and accept it as solution, not for the points in this answer its ok , but this is how StackOverflow works, helps people that answer and people that search for working soltuions.

Comment: Yup tried to upvote it but I need more reps for that!

Comment: ok there is a button also to accept answer or not, only you that asked see that, you press that if answer works, no worries about this answer i don't really mind, just saying for next ones : ), hoped it helped that answer

Comment: Havent quite got it to work just yet, but hopefully soon. I will take this time to read a bit about aggregation because I have basically zero understanding of it!

Comment: no worries at all, gl with your readings :) MongoDB documentation is very good with examples.

Comment: Got it working, thank you for introducing me aggregation!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this:

```
model.aggregate([ 
          {$lookup: {from: "cards", localField: "cards", foreignField: "_id", as: "cards"}},
          {$set: {clickSum: {$sum: "$cards.clicks"}}},
          {$sort: {clickSum: -1}}
            ])
```